# chocolatey: install programs from both internet and local Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, installer, chocolatey

I would like to prepare package.config file for the next time I have to restore Win7 to my netbook.

Most of my packages are in the chocolatey group of software, but some aren't.  Thus I have downloaded the non-chocolatey software and thus prepared the test config file below to see if chocolatey can mass install *.exe programs on a local drive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
    <package id="clipx-1.0.3.8-setup.exe" source="D:\AC\bckup\Install\3_Windows\04_PROGRAM_INSTALL_Manual\ClipX\clipx-1.0.3.8-setup.exe" />
    <package id="clipx-autoupdate-1.6-x86.exe" source="D:\AC\bckup\Install\3_Windows\04_PROGRAM_INSTALL_Manual\ClipX\clipx-autoupdate-1.6-x86.exe" />
    <package id="clipx-disklog-1.2-x86.exe" source="D:\AC\bckup\Install\3_Windows\04_PROGRAM_INSTALL_Manual\ClipX\clipx-disklog-1.2-x86.exe" />
    <package id="clipx-limits-1.2-x86.exe" source="D:\AC\bckup\Install\3_Windows\04_PROGRAM_INSTALL_Manual\ClipX\clipx-limits-1.2-x86.exe" />
    <package id="clipx-stickies-1.9-x86.exe" source="D:\AC\bckup\Install\3_Windows\04_PROGRAM_INSTALL_Manual\ClipX\clipx-stickies-1.9-x86.exe" />
</packages>
```

I also tried the above w/o the *.exe part of the path, but no matter what chocolatey can't install, reporting back that all 5 programs failed to install, more specifically:

```
Error serializing type chocolatey.infrastructure.app.configuration.ConfigFileSettings:
Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\config\chocolatey.config' is denied.
Error updating 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\config\chocolatey.config'. Please ensure you have permissions to do so:
Access to the path 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\config\chocolatey.config' is denied.
Chocolatey v0.9.9.4
Installing the following packages:
packages0426.config
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
clipx-1.0.3.8-setup.exe not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name exists but the version does not.
Version: ""
Source(s):     "D:\AC\bckup\Install\3_Windows\04_PROGRAM_INSTALL_Manual\ClipX\clipx-1.0.3.8-setup.exe"
clipx-autoupdate-1.6-x86.exe not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name exists but the version does not.
Version: ""
Source(s): "D:\AC\bckup\Install\3_Windows\04_PROGRAM_INSTALL_Manual\ClipX\clipx-autoupdate-1.6-x86.exe"
clipx-disklog-1.2-x86.exe not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name exists but the version does not.
Version: ""
Source(s): "D:\AC\bckup\Install\3_Windows\04_PROGRAM_INSTALL_Manual\ClipX\clipx-disklog-1.2-x86.exe"
clipx-limits-1.2-x86.exe not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name exists but the version does not.
Version: ""
Source(s): "D:\AC\bckup\Install\3_Windows\04_PROGRAM_INSTALL_Manual\ClipX\clipx-limits-1.2-x86.exe"
clipx-stickies-1.9-x86.exe not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
If you specified a particular version and are receiving this message, it is possible that the package name exists but the version does not.
Version: ""
Source(s): "D:\AC\bckup\Install\3_Windows\04_PROGRAM_INSTALL_Manual\ClipX\clipx-stickies-1.9-x86.exe"

Chocolatey installed 0/5 package(s). 5 package(s) failed.
See the log for details.
Failures:
 - clipx-1.0.3.8-setup.exe
 - clipx-stickies-1.9-x86.exe
 - clipx-disklog-1.2-x86.exe
 - clipx-autoupdate-1.6-x86.exe
 - clipx-limits-1.2-x86.exe
```

And yes, I certainly did do this from a cmd that was opened as an administrator.

Can chocolatey install *.exe programs locally?

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, **YES**, Chocolatey can install `*.exe` programs locally, but you still need a Chocolatey package pointing to those local native installers (`*.exe` files).

Chocolatey has the ability to install *directly* from a native installer, but only using Direct Installer (available in Chocolatey for Business).

So you still need the package (aka `.nupkg` file) that has install instructions pointing to your local native installers (e.g. `setup.exe`).